# UIScrollViewDelegate. scrollViewDidScroll not getting invoked (Swift/Interface Builder/Xcode 6)

Tags: swift, uikit, interface-builder, xcode6

I'm trying to hook up a scroll view using Interface Builder, and the `UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewDidScroll` method isn't getting invoked on scroll.

In IB, I have a view controller that uses my `PagedScrollViewController` as a custom class.  In that class, I have:

```
class PagedScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
        println("scrollViewDidScroll")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that `println` is never getting invoked.  I know that `PagedScrollViewController` is being connected correctly because if I add a `viewDidLoad` method, that gets invoked.  Is there something extra I need to do to attach the delegate other than setting the custom class?

Answer (score 8):

Turns out I needed to attach the scroll view's delegate to the the controller.  Here's what worked for me:

```
class PagedScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Yes.  You can also do this in Interface Builder by opening the Document Outline view and control drag from the scroll view to the view controller and then select `delegate` from the pop-up.

Comment: Thanks, @vacawama.  I feel like I tried this to no avail, but I'll try it again.